# Rewrite rules to change display URL in address bar?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

What Apache .htaccess code can I implement that will follow these rules:

If a user visits **url.com/locations/houston.html**,
the file at **url.com/rawlocations/houston.html** will be displayed while retaining **url.com/locations/houston.html** in the address bar.

Logic is as follows:

- Condition: if "**url.com/locations/houston.html**"
- Rewrite/redirect to "**url.com/rawlocations/houston.html**"
- Rewrite **/rawlocations/houston.html** as **/locations/houston.html**

I apologize if this is a duplicate question, I am having trouble creating this effect on my site.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: You know the technology involved, you know what you want to do: now the next, small step is to try it out

Comment: Sumurai8 yeah that looks like a great reference. Thank You!